# Why is there extra space in my JavaFX application?

Tags: java, javafx

I have the following application:

[image]

And there is a lot of unwanted white space on the far right of my application.

This is my `start()` method. Here, `initComponents()` just instantiates the controls on the application, and adds it to the grid pane.

```
primaryStage.setTitle("Music Masher");

gridPane = new GridPane();

initComponents();

root = new StackPane();
root.getChildren().add(gridPane);

primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
primaryStage.sizeToScene();
primaryStage.show();
```

In the `initComponents()` method, the only constraints changed in the grid pane are the following:

```
gridPane.setHgap(10);
gridPane.setVgap(15);
gridPane.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
```

The `TextFields` have a column span of 4, and some of the buttons have a column span of 2.

`initComponents()` method:

```
public void initComponents(){

    //Left components
    goBackLeft = new Button("<<");
    gridPane.add(goBackLeft, 0, 0);

    playButtonLeft = new Button("    Play    ");
    gridPane.add(playButtonLeft, 1, 0);
    gridPane.setColumnSpan(playButtonLeft, 2);

    goForwardLeft = new Button(">>");
    gridPane.add(goForwardLeft, 3, 0);

    songFieldLeft = new TextField();
    songFieldLeft.setEditable(false);
    gridPane.add(songFieldLeft, 0, 1);
    gridPane.setColumnSpan(songFieldLeft, 4);

    pickButtonLeft = new Button("Pick Song");
    gridPane.add(pickButtonLeft, 1, 2);
    gridPane.setColumnSpan(pickButtonLeft, 2);
    //End Left

    //Right components
    goBackRight = new Button("<<");
    gridPane.add(goBackRight, 5, 0);

    playButtonRight = new Button("    Play    ");
    gridPane.add(playButtonRight, 6, 0);
    gridPane.setColumnSpan(playButtonRight, 2);

    goForwardRight = new Button(">>");
    gridPane.add(goForwardRight, 8, 0);

    songFieldRight = new TextField();
    songFieldRight.setEditable(false);
    gridPane.add(songFieldRight, 5, 1);
    gridPane.setColumnSpan(songFieldRight, 4);

    pickButtonRight = new Button("Pick Song");
    gridPane.add(pickButtonRight, 6, 2);
    gridPane.setColumnSpan(pickButtonRight, 2);
    //End right

    mashButton = new Button("Mash!");
    gridPane.add(mashButton, 4, 3);

    gridPane.setHgap(10);
    gridPane.setVgap(15);
    gridPane.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));

}
```

Why is this extra space appearing? Does anyone know how to fix this? I've tried changing the width of the stage, but this skews the controls from their original location.

Comment: I don't understand why the text fields have a column span of 4 (should be 3 from the screenshot), though that won't create the extra space to the right. Can you post all the layout code for the grid pane?

Comment: Will post it now. But the "Play" button has a col span of 2, adding up to total of 4 cells.

Comment: OK, but why? There are no other columns the play button needs to span. Doesn't really matter though.

Comment: @James_D Code posted, that's the entirety of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why you are seeing the effect you're seeing, but I think the issue is that you essentially have a couple of completely empty columns (columns 2 and 7) and so, for some reason, the horizontal gaps associated with those columns are being pushed to the right and creating blank horizontal space. Just reworking the columns without the blank ones seems to fix it.

As an aside, to make the "Play" and "Pick Song" buttons the same width, don't try to pad the text with spaces: this will break horribly if you (or a user) changes the font. Instead, allow the buttons to grow (by setting their `maxWidth` to `Double.MAX_VALUE`), and set the `fillWidth` constraint on them to true, so they fill the width of their column.

```
public void initComponents(){

    //Left components
    goBackLeft = new Button("<<");
    gridPane.add(goBackLeft, 0, 0);

    playButtonLeft = new Button("Play");
    playButtonLeft.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
    GridPane.setFillWidth(playButtonLeft, true);
    gridPane.add(playButtonLeft, 1, 0);

    goForwardLeft = new Button(">>");
    gridPane.add(goForwardLeft, 2, 0);

    songFieldLeft = new TextField();
    songFieldLeft.setEditable(false);
    gridPane.add(songFieldLeft, 0, 1);
    GridPane.setColumnSpan(songFieldLeft, 3);

    pickButtonLeft = new Button("Pick Song");
    pickButtonLeft.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
    GridPane.setFillWidth(pickButtonLeft, true);
    gridPane.add(pickButtonLeft, 1, 2);

    //End Left

    //Right components
    goBackRight = new Button("<<");
    gridPane.add(goBackRight, 4, 0);

    playButtonRight = new Button("Play");
    playButtonRight.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
    GridPane.setFillWidth(playButtonRight, true);
    gridPane.add(playButtonRight, 5, 0);

    goForwardRight = new Button(">>");
    gridPane.add(goForwardRight, 6, 0);

    songFieldRight = new TextField();
    songFieldRight.setEditable(false);
    gridPane.add(songFieldRight, 4, 1);
    GridPane.setColumnSpan(songFieldRight, 3);

    pickButtonRight = new Button("Pick Song");
    pickButtonRight.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
    GridPane.setFillWidth(pickButtonRight, true);
    gridPane.add(pickButtonRight, 5, 2);

    //End right

    mashButton = new Button("Mash!");
    gridPane.add(mashButton, 3, 3);

    gridPane.setHgap(10);
    gridPane.setVgap(15);
    gridPane.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));

}
```

This gives me

[image]

Comment: Hm. Works now. Column spanning is a bit confusing to me, but I'm sure I'll get a hold of it. Appreciated :)

Comment: Don't use multiple columns to try to change the size of things: it doesn't do that. See update on making the "Play" and "Pick" buttons the same width.